# Kali Linux Live (Try before installation) won't install GRUB or LILO

Tags: system-installation, grub2, kali-linux, internet, cpu-frequency

I want to install Kali Linux but the original installation makes my PC hot. I use `cpufreq-selector -f 1000000` to cool down my PC, but when I use the live option, GRUB or LILO won't install. Do I have to be connected to the internet? Or is it a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, any "live" distribution will not make any changes to your computer (other hard disks/SSD's, etc) unless you explicitly tell them to.

That's one of their biggest advantages, you can try them out and not worry about changing your currently installed OS.

*PS.* I would search hard for an answer to why the PC gets too hot while running Kali... are the sensors reliable (they match the BIOS numbers, if you can get to BIOS fast enough before things cool/heat), does the fan speed up like it should, fan/grills blocked?